# Spark union taking a long time with 1 long-running task

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

[image]

Hi, In my spark job at a certain stage I am merging(union) 3 datasets with 300 partitions each. Here is the union stage of the job with the 900 tasks. As you can see, there is 1 task that runs for more than an hour. This does not happen always though. I know it is hard to figure out without looking at the data but are there any commons reasons for this kind of situation and guidelines to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue where I had to union a number of Spark Datasets before a join, and the join always ended up with only one long running task. So, I resolved it now. The problem is with the "join after union": what I observed is that the remaining one task was slowly processing ALL records! And my hypothesis is that the reason ALL records were ended up in one task was because of the shuffle. In my case, the join after the union could cause a shuffle, that is why I removed the join after the union, and now it works.

Basically, now I have to move the join before the union, so I just join each sub-dataset with the other dataset, then union the results (mine is left join so the results will still be the same).